# Box2D to SFML 1 pixel is being misplaced (only sometimes)

Tags: box2d, sfml

I have a weird problem which seems impossible to solve. The problem is that sometimes, only on some textures 1 pixel gets misplaced or pushed down for some weird reason.

[image]

I have the debug draw activated and it looks like like the sprite doesn't follow the body depending on where it is placed. This only happens when the character moves and it looks like flickering, as soon as I stand still, the pixel is back to its original place. Anyone here who encountered the same problem before and know how to solve it?

Problem found:

Using the debug draw to move the bodies around the game world, I found out that if i move the body only 1 pixel, sometimes the body gets reduced by 1 pixel while the sprite moves 1 pixel. In other words, all the sudden the body is one pixel shorter than the sprite which cause the flickering. Don't know how to solve it still but at least I know whats causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sf::view use integer values ( for position & size ), and disable the [smoothing](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Texture.php#a0c3bd6825b9a99714f10d44179d74324) on your textures.